# Write a Dictionary of dictionaries to plist

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have been scratching my head for the better part of the evening on this and I need some help.  I am trying to write nested Dictionaries to a plist for use elsewhere.  When I use the "writeToFile:atomically" nothing happens.  Is this even possible?  It works fine for simple dictionaries so I know I have the file paths set up properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for better understanding, can you provide some sample which you want to store in plist?

Comment: most likely there's some component in your "nested" dictionaries that doesn't have NSCoding/NSArchiver/NSUnarchiver abilities (i.e. a custom object of yours and *not* a NSNumber, NSString, etc).

Comment: I found an error in my code where I was string a custom object rather than the name property of the object and it is writing the file fine now.  However, in the meantime I decided to go with writing the dictionaries to XML instead as it will give me more flexibility in the end.  Thanks of the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but your dictionaries must only contains [types managed by plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2):
  - NSArray
  - NSDictionary
  - NSString
  - NSData
  - NSDate
  - NSNumber (int/float/bool)